# Making Sure That an Input is a Float

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

My current code:

```
while True:
    surjuv = input("What is the juvenile survival rate?")
    if surjuv.isinstance(float)==True and float(surjuv)<=1 and float(surjuv)>=0:
        break
```

It needs to make sure that `surjuv` is a float, but the following error comes up when 0.5 is entered:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 81, in <module>
File "python", line 21, in main_menu
File "python", line 51, in enter_gen0
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isinstance'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string is a number (float) in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for `isinstance` would be `isinstance(surjuv, float)`, but this will always fail in your case because Python 3 `input` returns a string.

Convert the input to a `float`, and when that fails do whatever error handling is necessary.

```
try:
    surjuv = float(input('...'))
except ValueError:
    continue # or whatever you want
```